# Recommendations for CRM SaaS?

Tags: crm, saas

Apologies if this isn't the right place to ask: I'm looking for recommendations for a commercial-grade service that will facilitate the management of a web-based business directory that we're building for a client. We need it to include:

**REST API** - our directory will need to push and pull data to/from it via a REST API.

**Custom data structure** inc. parent/child relationships - we need considerable control over the content schema, managing entities like "company", "location", "project".

**Role-based permissions** - the ability to create user groups with varying levels of access to view and edit content

**Field- and entity- level permissions** - the more granularity the better

**Event hooks / triggers** - the service should be able to react (i.e. send notification, or trigger API-based callback) when content is added or edited

**Workflow/publishing management** - the ability, at a minimum level, to control content availability to non-admin users via i.e. "published" or "approved" status.

**Reporting / analytics** - A bit of a nebulous one, but the ability for admin users to view system usage etc as a series of pretty graphs and pictures and stuff.

I'm looking at CRM solutions (Salesforce, Monday.com etc) to begin with as they seem to most closely align with these requirements. Do you know of any other SaaS offering that would be a close fit?